# Changing a canvas object's color using a button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am having trouble getting a button to work as intended in python 3. That being, that when it is pressed it changes the color of the circle from one color to another, beginning in red. However, when I run this program it simply begins as white instead of red nor does pressing the buttons change the color of the circle and I am very confused as to why.

```
from tkinter import *

def changeColor():
    test.itemconfig(circle, fill = "blue")

def changeColor2():
    test.itemconfig(circle, fill = "white")

root = Tk()
test = Canvas(root, width = 50, height = 50)
test.pack()
circle = test.create_oval(0, 0, 25, 25,fill="red")



button = Button(root,text="",command=changeColor(),bg= "blue")
button2= Button(root,text="",command=changeColor2(),bg= "white")
button.pack()
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

[From Wikibooks on Python](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Functions)

> Closures are possible in Python because functions are first-class objects. A function is merely an object of type function. Being an object means it is possible to pass a function object (an uncalled function) around as argument or as return value or to assign another name to the function object. A unique feature that makes closure useful is that the enclosed function may use the names defined in the parent function's scope.

The syntax for passing a function is the function name without the brackets:
command=changeColor